# Two questions about "to brim with"

Tags: verbs

> They **brim with** [negative quality]

I have two questions:

1. Can I use "brim" with a negative quality? Definitions and examples seem to use positive ones
2. Can I use "brim" or do I have to use "are brimming"? Dictionaries suggest using the present continuous form

Answer (score 3):

It's unusual, but I see no reason why you can't use "brim" with a negative quality. In this context "brim" is short for "filled to the brim", in other words with no room for any more, at maximum capacity.
Again you could say either, but more likely "Great scientists are brimming with self-doubt".

Comment: I would say that scientists _are brimming_ implies a current condition, whereas scientists _brim_ might suggest an occasional one.

Comment: You don't even provide a definition...

Answer (score 2):

*Brimming with **tears,*** which is obviously "negative", is by far the most common usage.

But that's effectively a *literal* usage (referencing "overflowing liquid"). We rarely use figurative ***brim*** in negative contexts, so the OP's example looks weird to me. [According to Google NGrams,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=brimming%20with%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) the most common referents after ***tears*** are ***confidence, energy, excitement, life, enthusiasm, ideas, love...***

---

Regarding the verb form itself, the continuous form (not so common in most *other* contexts) is [used as often as Simple Past/Present](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is%20brimming%20with%20life%2Cbrims%20with%20life&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) with figurative ***to be brimming with [good thing]...***

[image]

Comment: _Brimming with doubt, the narrator cravenly admits to being a "parasite" on Cassandra's unyielding sense of outrage and purpose – but quickly falls into step._ (Review of 2012 novel in the _Independent_ She brims with doubt.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I said ***rarely***, not ***never***. I think your cited example is just a reviewer revelling in writing "unusual" phrasing.

Comment: ...but I will accept that [*brimming with **wrath***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22brimming+with+wrath%22) has had some currency in "purple prose literature" over the centuries! :)

Comment: These ngrams are so useless. If one does not have these things internalized, it's a futile endeavor. **brimming with negativity**//**brimming with hastily drawn conclusions**//**brimming with venom**, **a barrel brimming with bitter vetch** You can take any container at all and have it brim with any number of things, figuratively and literally.

Comment: I didn't need to consult NGrams to tell me that ***brimming with X*** is normally used with *positive* attributes, because that's what I already thought. Obviously there's nothing to stop OP using it with *negative* attributes, but the fact of the matter is *some* people (including me) will think it's slightly odd. Let's face it - most learners are *already* "marked out" because they make mistakes. Do they really want to pile on the agony by deliberately choosing less common versions of idiomatic figurative usages?

Comment: (It's worth bearing in mind that the OP obviously had a *reason* for specifically asking whether it's okay to use figurative ***brimming*** with negative attributes. And most likely that reason was *because he doesn't see many examples.*)

Answer (score 1):

The brim of a container is its edge.

Here is the best definition I have found for learning purposes:

> The brim is the top of a container, like the edge of a cup. Also, if a
> cup is brimming, it’s full.
>
> This word has a couple meanings related to fullness. If a cup is full,
> it’s filled to the brim. The brim is the top. Containers such as
> buckets and pitchers have brims too. Also, the bucket is brimming if
> it's totally full. A brimming container is likely to spill. People can
> brim too: you can be brimming with enthusiasm or happiness. Like a cup
> about to spill, you can’t quite contain yourself when you’re brimming
> with joy.

[vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/brim)

So, now, you can brim with happiness etc. but you can also be brimming with sadness. **Whatever the underlying image, such as a cup or other vessel or person-as-vessel that holds something, what is being held can be negative, positive or indifferent or a physical thing.**

For example:

- He was brimming with negative expectations.
- He was brimming with great expectations. (Thank you Dickens)
- The barrel was brimming with flowers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think one can “brim with a lack of” something, or “brim with emptiness.”  A vessel can’t be full of emptiness!  Other than solecism like those, though, sure.

Comment: Donna Summer, were she able, might disagree- her song “Full of Emptiness” was a hit in the seventies.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany It’s a nice, poetic play on words.